# Source Engine - Getting team score

Tags: source-engine

How can i get teamscore in code?in hl2mp_gamerules.cpp i found this:

```
        CTeam *pCombine = g_Teams[TEAM_COMBINE];
        CTeam *pRebels = g_Teams[TEAM_REBELS];

        if ( pCombine->GetScore() >= flFragLimit || pRebels->GetScore() >= flFragLimit )
        {
```

And here's how i modified in my .cpp file:

```
CTeam *pRebels = GetGlobalTeam( TEAM_REBELS );
CTeam *pCombine = GetGlobalTeam( TEAM_COMBINE );

CBasePlayer *pPlayer = UTIL_PlayerByIndex(engine->GetLocalPlayer());

  if(pCombine->GetScore() == 1)
  {
    vgui::surface()->DrawSetColor(GetFgColor());
    vgui::surface()->DrawSetTexture( m_nTeamBlue );
    vgui::surface()->DrawTexturedRect(0, 0, GetWide(), GetTall());
  }
```

But it says: pRebels, pCombine, cTeam are undeclared identifiers. How can i declare them? Or what .h file i need to include?